# "On" versus "off"

Tags: word-choice

We're having a debate in our office as to which of the following is grammatically correct:

> Get savings of up to 75% **off** name brand clothes […].
>   Get savings of up to 75% **on** name brand clothes […].
>   Get savings of up to 75% **off of** name brand clothes […].

Please help us settle this!

Comment: Although it's syntactically valid, I doubt many people would actually *write* Option C. But I'm sure it's often spoken, where it wouldn't be so noticably ungainly.

Comment: I can also imagine seeing OPTION D "Get savings of up to 75% OFF ON name brand clothes..."

Answer (score 3):

There's a bit of a tangle here. The three players are:

- *savings **on** name-brand clothes*
- *a savings **of** 75%*
- *75% **off***

> A. *“Get savings of up to 75% **off** name-brand clothes…”*
>   = *“The savings you can get **on** name-brand clothes are up to **75% off**”*

Option A simply omits *on*. Arguably it's kinda awkward: saying *the savings are 75%* is much nicer than *the savings are 75% off*, unless you're about to say *…off list price* or something, but then I'd likely prefer *25% of list* to avoid confusion.

> B. *“Get savings of up to 75% **on** name-brand clothes…”*
>   = *“The savings you can get **on** name-brand clothes are up to **75%**”*

This is the option I'd go for. Straight to the point.

> C. *“Get savings of up to 75% **off of** name-brand clothes…”*
>   = *“The savings you can get **off of** name-brand clothes are up to **75%**”*

…No.

Answer (score 3):

The second sentence is the most correct of your options, since the savings is not off the clothes, it is off the *price* of the clothes.

Answer (score 2):

The first option may not be logical but it is idiomatic and it's what you usually hear:

> OPTION A "Get savings of up to 75% OFF
>   name brand clothes..."

What's happening here is probably linguistic elision, i.e., "[Buy now and] get savings [that amount to] 75% off [the price of] name brand clothes."

In rapid-fire ad-speak, this is normal and universally understood. You'll also hear "on" but "off" is probably the more-common usage.

Answer (score 1):

How about just "Save up to 75% on name-brand clothes..." ? Or is the "Get" really important to you? Or you might use "discounts," as in "get discounts up to 75% on name-brand clothes...". But if it has to be one these choices and it has to be correct, I'd go with A.

Answer (score 0):

Correctness of utterances will vary between listeners. Some utterances would be pretty much universally regarded and incorrect English, and others would be pretty much universally regarded as correct. The fact that you're debating this suggests that these may be somewhere in between.

Personally I'd regard them all as correct, but with a preference for "Get savings of up to 75% **on** name brand clothes"